# VS Code access to live server extension from another device

Tags: visual-studio-code, port

I want to see my website preview from my phone.
I just changed this setting and it was working fine.

[image]

It was working fine when my phone and computer are connected to same modem.

But when i connected another internet from my phone i cant access to live server

I am using 5500 port there is nothing running,
i gave access to 5500 port from firewall.

Comment: Your question could be a possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are in local network you write pc local ip in the address, if you are in another network, you write the public ip address of the pc + port.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).